# Выбор из 2 таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть таблица movies и таблица posters, таблицу posters связывает поле id_movies с таблицей movies с полем id 
Вот нужно вытащить всё из movies и его фотографию из таблицы posters, а фотография имеет поле url
вот что набросал, но это не то, т.к нужно вытащить именно фотографию где id_movies равен id
вот sql:

> SELECT
> movies.id,movies.name,movies.year,movies.main_role,movies.description,poster.url
> FROM movies,poster ORDER BY id DESC
> LIMIT :num,12

Вот дамп 2 таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movies` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `main_role` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=77 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posters` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_movies` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=39 ;
```

UPD:
Вроде решил проблему, насколько правильно?

> SELECT
> movies.id,movies.name,movies.year,movies.main_role,movies.description,posters.url
> FROM movies,posters WHERE
> posters.id_movies = movies.id ORDER BY
> id DESC LIMIT :num,12

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего запрос будет выглядеть

```
SELECT m.*, p.url 
FROM `movies` m
LEFT JOIN `posters` p
ON m.id = p.id_movies 
order by id DESC LIMIT 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал это с помощью JOIN:

```
SELECT m.*, p.url 
FROM `movies` m
LEFT JOIN `posters` p
ON m.id = p.id_movies
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7e3b8/1)

Comment: Небольшой комментарий. * в SQL-запросах - не очень хорошая практика.